# How to de/activate HDR option in camera with code?

Tags: unity, camera

I have some glowing objects in my scene, that with HDR off are inactive, so i want to add the option to turn HDR off in my settings to increase performance.

If the code bellow is correct, what should i write inside get component:

```
public GameObject currentActiveCamera;
currentActiveCamera.GetComponent<???>.hdr = false;
```

Comment: Shows lack of research. Just searching for camera and going down to HDR part in Unity Docs fixes this problem.

Comment: @JohnHamilton i did, found nothing!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html do Ctrl+F type in hdr. That's a boolean that shows whether the HDR is enabled on that camera or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `GameObject` type, use `Camera`.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;


    public class CameraManager: MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public Camera currentActiveCamera;

        void Start()
        {
            currentActiveCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().hdr = false;
        }
    }
```